# RuntimeExecutionException: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 8

Tags: android, android-intent, gmail-api, google-signin

I am creating an application to manage Gmail Mails,
Here I am stuck while login/authentication

on sign in Button onClick I am running below code

```
startActivityForResult(mCredential.newChooseAccountIntent(), RC_SIGN_IN);
```

and getting error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=121, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {.MainActivity}: com.google.android.gms.tasks.RuntimeExecutionException: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 8: 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4398)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4440)
    at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:49)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1816)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6718)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 Caused by: com.google.android.gms.tasks.RuntimeExecutionException: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 8: 
    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu.getResult(Unknown Source:15)
    at .MainActivity.handleSignInResult(MainActivity.java:145)
    at .MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:139)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7462)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4391)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4440) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:49) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1816) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6718) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
 Caused by: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 8: 
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.ApiExceptionUtil.fromStatus(Unknown Source:4)
    at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(Unknown Source:6)
    at .MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:138)
```

Does anyone know the reason or solution please?

Comment: Same problem, what is interesting is that if you click the sign in button again it will work